# Generalized limits in Boolean algebras

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory, limits-and-convergence, boolean-algebras, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathbb{B}$ be an infinite $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra. By $\mathbb{B}^\omega$ we denote the countable product of $\mathbb{B}$ with the coordinate-wise operations. Let us call a homomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb{B}^\omega\to\mathbb{B}$ *generalized limit* if for every sequence $(A_n)\in\mathbb{B}^\omega$ we have:

$\bigvee_{n\in\omega}\bigwedge_{k\ge n} A_k\le\varphi(A_n)\le\bigwedge_{n\in\omega}\bigvee_{k\ge n}A_k$.

(I guess it's immediately visible, why $\varphi$ is called *limit*.)

Are you aware of some standard way of constructing in ZFC such generalized limits? I am especially interested in the case of $\mathbb{B}$ being a measure algebra, e.g. $\mathbb{B}=\mathrm{Bor}([0,1])/\mathcal{N}$ (here $\mathcal{N}$ stands for the Lebesgue null ideal), but of course any general study will be useful.

I will appreciate any answer, hint, or reference to a research paper.

Comment: @JosephVanName, the more nice properties $\varphi$ has, the better, but if it's impossible to construct $\sigma$-complete $\varphi$, then I'll be happy to see a construction of a non-$\sigma$-complete one

Comment: Fix a non-principal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$. There is a homomorphism $\mathbb{B}^\omega$ to the ultrapower $\mathbb{B}^\omega/\mathcal{U}$. And *I think* that if $\mathbb{B}$ is complete, then there is a "standard part" homomorphism $\mathbb{B}^\omega/\mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{B}$, mapping each element of the ultrapower to the meet of the set of elements of $\mathbb{B}$ which are above it. The composition of these homomorphisms should satisfy your definition.

Comment: But (1) we just get a BA homomorphism, not a $\sigma$-complete one, (2) I used completeness of $\mathbb{B}$, not just $\sigma$-completeness, and (3) I haven't checked the details.

Comment: @AlexKruckman. I think the details follow just from the Sikorski extension theorem (or maybe you can use Boolean-valued models).

Comment: @AlexKruckman, thanks for the idea! But could you explain more precisely what you understand by "mapping each element of the ultrapower to the meet of the set of elements of $\mathbb{B}$ which are above it"?

Comment: "mapping each element of the ultrapower to the meet of the set of elements of B which are above it."-This will not work since that mapping is not a Boolean algebra homomorphism; we have to use the Sikorski extension theorem instead (which gives a non-unique homomorphism). Suppose that $A$ is the Boolean algebra freely generated by $(x_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ and $B=\overline{A}$ is its completion. Let $j:B^{\omega}/\mathcal{U}\rightarrow B$ be the function mapping each element to the meet of the elemnts that are above it.

Comment: Suppose that for each $n\in\omega$ either $y_{n}=x_{n}$ or $y_{n}=x_{n}'$. Then if $(y_{n})_{n\in\omega}/\mathcal{U}\leq(c)_{n}/\mathcal{U}$, then $\{n\in\omega\mid y_{n}\leq c\}\in\mathcal{U}$, so $y_{n}\leq c$ for infinitely many $n$. This is only possible if $c=1$, so $j((y_{n})_{n\in\omega})=1$. We can now conclude that $j$ does not preserve complementation.

Comment: @JosephVanName Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Boolean algebra $B$ is complete, then I claim that there exists generalized limits. I am going to generalize this answer from limits indexed by $\omega$ to a limit of a net indexed by an arbitrary directed set.

Let $B$ be a complete Boolean algebra. Suppose that $D$ is a directed set. Then
let $I$ be the ideal on $B^{D}$ consisting of all $(b_{d})_{d\in D}$ where there exists some $e\in D$ where $b_{d}=0$ for all $d\geq e.$

Proposition: Suppose that $\varphi:B^{D}\rightarrow B$ is a Boolean algebra homomorphism. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $$\varphi((b_{d})_{d\in D})\leq\bigwedge_{d\in D}\bigvee_{e\geq d}b_{e}$$ for each tuple $(b_{d})_{d\in D}\in B^{D}$.
2. $$\bigvee_{d\in D}\bigwedge_{e\geq d}b_{e}\leq\varphi((b_{d})_{d\in D})$$ for each tuple $(b_{d})_{d\in D}\in B^{D}$.
3. $$\varphi(x)=0$$ whenever $x\in I$, and $\varphi((b)_{d\in D})=b$.
4. There is a Boolean algebra homomorphism $f:B^{D}/I\rightarrow B$ such that $f((b)_{d\in D}+I)=b$ for all $b\in B$ and where if $\pi_{I}:B^{D}\rightarrow B^{D}/I$ is the quotient mapping, then
   $\varphi=f\pi_{I}.$

Proof outline: The equivalence between 1 and 2 follows by taking complementation. The equivalence between 3 and 4 follows from the first isomorphism theorem applied to Boolean algebras.

$(1\wedge 2)\rightarrow 3$. If $(b_{d})_{d\in D}\in I$, then there is some $d\in D$ where $b_{e}=0$ for $e\geq d$. Therefore,
$$\varphi((b_{d})_{d\in D})\leq\bigvee_{e\geq d}b_{e}=0.$$
Furthermore, we have $$\varphi((b)_{d\in D})\leq\bigwedge_{d\in D}\bigvee_{e\geq d}b=b\leq\bigvee_{d\in D}\bigwedge_{e\geq d}b\leq\varphi((b)_{d\in D}),$$ so
$\varphi((b)_{d\in D})=b.$

$(3\wedge 4)\rightarrow 1.$ Let $\varphi,\pi_{I},f$ be the mappings stated in the proposition where $\varphi=f\pi_{I}$.

Let $(b_{d})_{d\in D}\in B^{D}$, and suppose that $d_{0}\in D$. Let $b=\bigvee_{e\geq d_{0}}b_{e}$. Then

$\pi_{I}(b_{d})_{d\in D}\leq\pi_{I}((b)_{d\in D})$. Therefore,
$$\varphi(b_{d})_{d\in D}=f\pi_{I}(b_{d})_{d\in D}\leq f\pi_{I}((b)_{d\in D})
=\varphi((b)_{d\in D})=b=\bigvee_{e\geq d_{0}}b_{e}.$$

We conclude that
$$\varphi(b_{d})_{d\in D}\leq\bigwedge_{d_{0}\in D}\bigvee_{e\geq d_{0}}b_{e}.$$

Q.E.D

The mappings $f:B^{D}/I\rightarrow B$ such that $f((b)_{d\in D}+I)=b$ for all $b\in B$ can be obtained using Sikorski's extension theorem, so just let $\varphi=f\pi_{I}$ to obtain your generalized limits.